# ESRP CodeSigning tasks are failing in azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to do a build using yml based azure devops pipeline. But the build is being broke by the task(ESRP Code Signing) provided by the VSTS pipeline.

The task I am referring to :

```
- task: SFP.build-tasks.custom-build-task-1.EsrpCodeSigning@1
```

ErrorCode: invalid_client

StatusCode: 401

Could anyone help how to overcome this error?